# Ada Task Declaration Causes Memory Leak

Tags: memory-leaks, valgrind, ada

I have the following little Ada program:

```
procedure Leaky_Main is 
   task Beer;
   task body Beer is 
   begin 
      null;
   end Beer;
begin 
   null;
end Leaky_Main;
```

All fairly basic, but when i compile like this:

```
gnatmake -g -gnatwI leaky_main.adb
```

and run it through Valgrind like this :

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck -v --leak-check=full --read-var-info=yes --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./leaky_main
```

I get the following error summary:

```
==2882== 2,104 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==2882==    at 0x4028876: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==2882==    by 0x42AD3B8: __gnat_malloc (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnat-4.4.so.1)
==2882==    by 0x40615FF: system__task_primitives__operations__new_atcb (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnarl-4.4.so.1)
==2882==    by 0x406433C: system__tasking__initialize (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnarl-4.4.so.1)
==2882==    by 0x4063C86: system__tasking__initialization__init_rts (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnarl-4.4.so.1)
==2882==    by 0x4063DA6: system__tasking__initialization___elabb (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnarl-4.4.so.1)
==2882==    by 0x8049ADA: adainit (b~leaky_main.adb:142)
==2882==    by 0x8049B7C: main (b~leaky_main.adb:189)
==2882== 
==2882== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2882==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2882==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2882==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2882==    still reachable: 2,104 bytes in 1 blocks
==2882==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2882== 
==2882== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 21 from 6)
--2882-- 
--2882-- used_suppression:     21 U1004-ARM-_dl_relocate_object
==2882== 
==2882== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 21 from 6)
```

Does anyone know why this is being reported as an error ? 
Im fairly sure there is no actual leak, but i would like to know why/how it happens.

Thanks,

Comment: where is there an error? 0 errors, 0 bytes lost...

Comment: @oenone : "still reachable: 2,104 bytes in 1 blocks"

Comment: where's the problem? the memory is still reachable. that's no error and not reported as such.

Comment: When Memory is reachable _after_ program termination, it is a leak, that is a problem. As Simon pointed out, its probably due to a known bug.

Comment: I don't think it is a problem. It may be not ideal, but the operating system frees any memory the process used anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problematic allocation looks to be the task control block (TCB). This has to be retained after the task has completed so that you can say

```
if Beer’Terminated then
   ...
```

so I think it’s probably an artefact of when `valgrind` does thecheck.

I’ve only come across this where the task was allocated; it was necessary to wait until `’Terminated` was `True` before deallocating the task, or GNAT happily deallocated the stack but silently didn’t deallocate the TCB, leading to a real leak like yours. AdaCore recently fixed this (I don’t have the reference, it was on their developer log).

Comment: Thanks Simon, This looks like a plausible explanation. Ill write a suppression for valgrind to deal with it :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use deleaker for debugging. I prefer it)

Comment: Not relevant for Ada development.